# Using swipe to trigger click

Tags: jquery, html, click, swipe

Apologies if this is basic but I'm learning.
I've coded a site using standard  links to navigate. I now want to also trigger the links using swipe, swipeleft and swiperight.

I've tried the following but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My existing code is a simple link with an image -

`<a href="a.html" title="Enter"><img src="any.gif" /></a>`

The jquery I tried to add (amongst others) was -

`$(document).on('swipe','img',function() { $('img').click(); });`

So the intension was that if the screen is swiped at all, then the image being clicked would be simulated - but that's clearly way too simple, I guess.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to review `.trigger()`. I also do not see an issue with the code, what is not working? Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You swipe, nothing happens.

Comment: I suspect that your `.on()` is to focused. Can you adjust to something like: `$(document).on('swipe', 'img',function(e){ console.log("Swipe.", e); $('img').click(); });`

Comment: Clicking an image would do nothing.  You could try to trigger click which should then bubble the event up to the `a` or you could call click on the link directly: `$(this).closest("a").click()`

Comment: Thanks, but none of these work. Or not consistently - sometimes the swipe appears to work, not always.